# Set a pic as background image of a TListColumn in BCB

Tags: c++builder, tlistview

I can set the ImageIndex  of a TListColumn to add a picture at the right of the ListColumn,show as:

[image]

But is there any way to set a background image for a TListColumn;

Or in another way,how can I acheive the effect looks like this(Windows Explorer):
[image]

How can I show the little triangle in my program?

Answer (score 0):

The ListView column header is a standard Win32 [Header Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775239.aspx).  You can retreive the HWND of the ListView's header using [`ListView_GetHeader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761290.aspx), and then use [`Header_SetItem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775423.aspx) to enable/disable the `HDF_SORTDOWN` and `HDF_SORTUP` flag on each column as needed.

However, the `HDF_SORT...` flags do not work if your app is not using Runtime Themes, or if the column has an image applied (is using the `HDF_IMAGE` or `HDF_BITMAP` flag).